# Cant remove oem.inf

Tags: windows, windows-7, usb, driver, inf

I am trying to remove a USB controller, but I am facing the following problem:

I opened a windows console as administrator and run `pnputil -e` to get the complete list of controllers installed

The controller I want to uninstall showed up as oem38.inf

I executed: `pnputil -f -d oem38.inf` to remove it, but got an error saying that it cant be uninstalled because the specified filename is not an installed OEM INF.

Any idea on how can I fix this?

My O.S is: Windows 7 Ultimate - Service Pack 1

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The command `pnputil -f -d oem46.inf` worked for me on Windows 10 when I ran it as Administrator, resulting in this output:

```
Microsoft PnP Utility

Driver package deleted successfully.
```

You should run `pnputil -enum-drivers` and make sure `oem38.inf` shows up in the list.  If it is not listed, maybe you already deleted it.  If you continue to have trouble, please update your question with the output from `pnputil -enum-drivers` and the full output from `pnputil -f -d oem38.inf`.

Comment: He pretty much already stated the error and the force flag does not help.  _Deleting the driver package failed : The specified file is not an installed OEM INF._

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation.
And I think I might know why the "not an installed oem inf" shows.
I think in the oemXX.inf part, output by pnputil /e, the XX must be a continuous number.
And I installed same driver twice by accident.
In my case, oem31.inf and oem32.inf are same driver.(one is certificated, one is not.)
They have same DriverVer.
When I try to delete oem32.inf, oem31.inf is deleted.
(Because they have same DriverVer? the first one can be deleted?)
Then when I try to delete oem32.inf again, the message shows.